# getting id of marker on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails to add a map to my rails app.
I'm trying to log the age of a user by clicking on marker.

In my index action I have -

```
    @json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails do |user, marker|
      marker.json({ :id => user.id, :age => user.age })
    end
```

This is creating the map and adding all my markers.

If I put Gmaps.map.markers[0] in my js console I can see my object and can see it has an age property.

I'm trying to log that property through a click by doing something like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <  this.markers.length; ++i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(
     Gmaps.map.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', function() { console.log(this.age) });
  }
 };        
</script>
```

this.age is undefined. Obviously, it is logging the serviceObject rather than the marker object.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're working with a closure and you're running into a problem where 'this' doesn't refer to the object that you think it does. In order to reference Gmaps.map.markers[*], first create an immediate function, pass in 'i' by value, and return a function that logs the .age property:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <  this.markers.length; ++i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(
     marker.serviceObject, 'click', (function(i) {
        return function() {
            console.log(Gmaps.map.markers[i].age) 
        }
    })(i));
  }
 };        
</script>
```

Declaring functions (closures) in loops can be tricky. Here's a very helpful walk-through explanation I found: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Comment: nice blog post, closures do tend to hurt my head a bit sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

To use a closure properly, do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <  Gmaps.map.markers.length; ++i) {
    marker = Gmaps.map.markers[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(
     marker.serviceObject, 'click', function() { console.log(marker.age) });
  }
 };        
</script>
```

Comment: Simple now I see it done properly. Thanks v much. Loving the gem btw, really looking forward to the openlayers version completed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't planned to work on it: I'm quite busy but opened to contributions

Comment: I'm still very much a rails beginner, but I'll definitely try and contribute when I can.

Comment: :) the part you're interested in is much more coffeescript/javascript than Rails

Comment: You should test this first, I think you'll find that this code will always log the age of the last item in the markers array because of the line: marker = map.markers[i]; //(marker is declared globally).

Comment: sorry to remove your answer, but Elliot's right. Still, I can't thank you enough for the work you've put into that gem

Comment: :D you could keep the +1 though :)